# Finding longest sequence of digits without using arrays in C

Tags: c, loops, sequence

I'm doing a C programming course and one of my tasks is to write a program that reads, from the standard input, an integer, and prints to the standard
output, the digit that occurs in the longest consecutive sequence. If there are multiple consecutive longest sequences, print the digit that is the smallest. 1 caveat is that we're not allowed to use arrays to solve this.

Examples of input/output: input `1122` / output `1`, input `800100022` / output `0`.

I have created a function to iterate through the input number, identify the longest sequence and return the corresponding digit but I'm not sure why this algorithm doesn't work for some cases. I need some help identifying some logical flaws in my code. Thank you very much

```
long get_digit(long n) {
    long prev_digit = 0;
    long freq = 0;
    long max_freq;
    long most_freq_digit = 0;
    //flag to symbolise first iteration
    long flag = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (flag == 0) {
            freq += 1;
            most_freq_digit = n % 10;
        } else {
            if (n % 10 == prev_digit) {
                freq += 1;
            }
            if (n % 10 != prev_digit || n < 10) {
                if (freq > max_freq) {
                    max_freq = freq;
                    most_freq_digit = prev_digit;
                } else
                if (freq == max_freq) {
                    if (prev_digit <= most_freq_digit) {
                        most_freq_digit = prev_digit;
                    }
                }
                freq = 1;
            }
        }
        flag += 1;
        prev_digit = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return most_freq_digit;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give examples of numbers which don't give you the output you expect.

Comment: You did not set `max_freq`'s initial value. Which could be a garbage value like 123451 and easily break your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not initialize `max_freq`, so the whole function has undefined behavior.
- the tests o `flag` and on `(n % 10 != prev_digit || n < 10)` to update `max_freq` and `most_freq_digit` are cumbersome: you could simplify the logic by handling the first digit outside the loop.
- you do not handle negative numbers.

Here is a simpler version:

```c
long get_digit(long n) {
    long div = n < 0 ? -10 : 10;
    long freq = 1;
    long digit = n % div;
    long max_freq = freq;
    long most_freq_digit = digit;
    while (n != 0) {
        if (n % div == digit) {
            freq += 1;
        } else {
            digit = n % div;
            freq = 1;
        }
        if (freq > max_freq || (freq == max_freq && digit < most_freq_digit)) {
            max_freq = freq;
            most_freq_digit = digit;
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return most_freq_digit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess this is your answer in short way
this two function give you smallest digit in number and largest

The main algorithm is this

1. get mod of number by 10 and store in temp
2. divide number by 10
3. get new mod and compare to temp if is smaller swap them
4. keep going until number be 0

```
int getSmallestDigit(int num) {
    int smallest;
    int temp;

    smallest = num % 10;
    num /= 10;

    while (num > 0) {
        temp = num % 10;
        if (temp < smallest) {
            smallest = temp;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return smallest;
}

int getLargestDigit(int num) {
    int large;
    int temp;

    large = num % 10;
    num /= 10;

    while (num > 0) {
        temp = num % 10;
        if (temp > large) {
            large = temp;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return large;
}
```